# foreach function for more than 2 array

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I need to insert data to a table.. the data come from different sources. The following are my code.

```
$title = array(Book A, Book B, Book C);
$number = array(2,1,4);
$lines = array(Maria, Smith, Abner);

for($i=1; $i<count($lines); $i++)
{
   print '<tr>';
   print '<td>'.$title[$i].'</td>';
   print '<td>P'.$number[$i].'</td>';
   print '<td>['.$lines[$i].']</td>';
   print '<td></td>';
   print '</tr>';
}
```

Seems not working :/ the array not display properly in my table.

I'm expecting output as follows:

```
------------------------------------------------
| Title     |    No    | Lines       | Remarks |
------------------------------------------------
| Book A    |    2     | Maria       |         |
| Book B    |    1     | Smith       |         |
| Book C    |    4     | Abner       |         |
------------------------------------------------
```

at the moment.. I get the following output:

```
------------------------------------------------
| Title     |    No    | Lines       | Remarks |
------------------------------------------------
|  Book A   |    2     | Maria       |         |
|           |          | Smith       |         |
|           |          | Abner       |         |
------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Is that `php` code? You should correctly tag your question

Comment: yes @Alon.. it is php code.. sorry.. will include the tag..

Comment: Please past a picture of a screenshot of how the table looks for us to see what is happening.

Comment: plz send your array structure, then we can decide to print using foreach(key-value).

Comment: What do you see when you do `print_r($title); print_r($number); print_r($lines);`?

Comment: Your code is just fine but checks if your inputs is in the right format.

Comment: Make keys of all three arrays same.

Comment: array for $title = (Book A, Book B, Book C), array for $number = (2,1,4) and array for $lines = (maria, smith, abner). The program will output in a table shows Book A | 2 | Maria and the rest of the array

Comment: When you put $z=1 and $z=2 in $number array,do you find values?

Comment: chances are your $title and $bitnum arrays aren't being populated the way you think they are.  maybe show us the code you use to populate those arrays.

Comment: @KorreyD those array comes from different function.. $title is from db, $number from search function to calculate words in a text file and $Lines is an input from form.. Its a function to calculate how many frequent a particular word used in a book.

Comment: @julie please delete the 4th td.Why do you want it if it does not show any value?maybe it is blocking the view somehow of the next rows?

Comment: @KorreyD BTW.. i know that the array contains correct data that i want because if I only display data from 2 array..(eg $title and $lines) the output display properly..

Comment: @Debojyoti that is for Remarks section.. need it to be emptied as for now.. Later I need to include another function to provide remarks..

Comment: @Debojyoti When i put value as follows: **$title[1], $number [1] , $lines[1]** .. the output display perfectly. But it will repeat 3 times since its looping according to the 'for' function **for($i=1; $i<count($lines); $i++)**

Comment: Also your $i should start with zero

Comment: still doesn't display properly.. BTW.. i get this **Message: Undefined offset: 2** at line **print '<td>'.$title[$i].'</td>';**

Comment: @julie the above statement means that $title[2] doesnt have any value assigned to it

Comment: @julie can you test using foreach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your arrays has different keys you can 'reset' them to be zero-based. Just use `$array = array_values($array)`. Quote from [manual](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php)

> array_values() returns all the values from the array and indexes the array numerically.

After this you code will work. This is how your example can be modified:

```php
$title = array('Book A', 'Book B', 'Book C');
$number = array("a" => 2, "b" => 1, "c" => 4);
$lines = array('Maria', 'Smith', 7 => 'Abner');
/* At this point you have some arrays with unknown keys.
   It can be [0 => item, 1 => item2] or ['name' => item, 'name2' => item2]
   or even with skipped keys [0 => item, 7 => item2]
*/


// Reset keys for all arrays. Now all arrays will contain keys 0, 1, 2 etc.
$title = array_values($title);
$number = array_values($number);
$lines = array_values($lines);

for($i = 0; $i < count($lines); $i++) // Note, arrays now are zero-based, you must start from $i = 0
{
    print '<tr>';
    print '<td>'.$title[$i].'</td>';
    print '<td>P'.$number[$i].'</td>';
    print '<td>['.$lines[$i].']</td>';
    print '<td></td>';
    print '</tr>';
}
```

Comment: i dont get it.. care to give example?

Comment: You are wrong. As OP says, "data come from different sources". We cannot be sure that all keys in arrays will be numeric. Please, read question before downvote. And `array_values()` is the simpliest way to set numeric keys in array.

Comment: Nice addition, @Frankie. Thanks for help!

Answer (score 1):

you just put i=0; because array started from 0 index and try following code may it help u.

```
    <?php $title = array('Book A','Book B','BookC');$number = array('2','1','4');$lines = array('Maria','Smith','Abner');for($i=0;$i<count($lines); $i++){print '<tr>';print '<td>'.$title[$i].'</td>';print '<td>P'.$number[$i].'</td>';print'<td>['.$lines[$i].']</td>';print '<td></td>'; print '</tr>'; } ?>
```

Comment: did change but still didnt get the expected output.

Comment: you just copy paste my code into dummy page and try it .it works well.

Comment: Thank you so much but it still not work because my index is not in sequence.. I got the solution from @Andrew.. Thanks again for your advice.

Comment: oh okay go ahead @Julie

Answer (score 1):

There's a neat trick to merging separate arrays with [`array_map()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) if you pass `null` as the first argument, followed by the arrays you want merged.

As quoted in **Example #4** in the docs:

> An interesting use of this function is to construct an array of arrays, which can be easily performed by using NULL as the name of the callback function

Using your example for context:

```
<?php

$titles  = ['Book A', 'Book B', 'Book C'];
$numbers = [2,1,4];
$lines   = ['Maria', 'Smith', 'Abner'];

// create an 'array of arrays'
$rows = array_map(null, $titles, $numbers, $lines);

var_dump($rows);
```

Yields:

```
array (size=3)
  0 => 
    array (size=3)
      0 => string 'Book A' (length=6)
      1 => int 2
      2 => string 'Maria' (length=5)
  1 => 
    array (size=3)
      0 => string 'Book B' (length=6)
      1 => int 1
      2 => string 'Smith' (length=5)
  2 => 
    array (size=3)
      0 => string 'Book C' (length=6)
      1 => int 4
      2 => string 'Abner' (length=5)
```

You can then iterate over it pretty easily, like so:

```
foreach ($rows as $row) {
    list($title, $number, $line) = $row;
    printf('<tr><td>%s</td><td>%s</td><td>%s</td></tr>',
        $title, $number, $line);
}
```

This should give you something like:

```
<tr><td>Book A</td><td>2</td><td>Maria</td></tr>
<tr><td>Book B</td><td>1</td><td>Smith</td></tr>
<tr><td>Book C</td><td>4</td><td>Abner</td></tr>
```

A useful side-effect of this approach is that your arrays do not have to be the same length; `null` will be used where applicable to pad out any "missing" values.

Another quick example:

```
<?php

$letters = range('a', 'd'); // ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
$numbers = range(1, 3);     // [1, 2, 3]
$merged  = array_map(null, $letters, $numbers);

var_dump($merged);
```

Yields:

```
array (size=4)
  0 => 
    array (size=2)
      0 => string 'a' (length=1)
      1 => int 1
  1 => 
    array (size=2)
      0 => string 'b' (length=1)
      1 => int 2
  2 => 
    array (size=2)
      0 => string 'c' (length=1)
      1 => int 3
  3 => 
    array (size=2)
      0 => string 'd' (length=1)
      1 => null
```

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try modifying you code as follow:

```
foreach($lines as $z => $value)
{
   print '<tr>';
   print '<td>'.$title[$z].'</td>';
   print '<td>P'.$number[$z].'</td>';
   print '<td>['.$value.']</td>';
   print '<td></td>';
   print '</tr>';
}
```

Comment: still not ok.. i got 'Message: Undefined offset: 0' at line >>> print '<td>'.$title[$z].'</td>';

Comment: Can you tell me the origin of `$title` & `$number` variables?

Comment: those array comes from different function.. $title is from db, $number from search function to calculate words in a text file and $Lines is an input from form.. Its a function to calculate how many frequent a particular word used in a book

Answer (score 0):

I found that the array index for all my array is not in sequential.

eg: $title =

array[0] = Book A

array[5] = Book B

array[9] = Book C

So, that is probably the reason why it is not display accordingly. I cannot use function 'for'. However, I cannot re-number the index because its the key for me to continue with next module/function.

So, I tried the following code.. but seems something missing..

```
$i=0;
if (!empty($title)){
foreach($title as $key => $value){
   $y = $number[$key];
   if ($i<count($lines))
   {   $z = $lines[$i];
       $i+1;
   }

   print '<tr>';
   print '<td>'.$value.'</td>';
   print '<td>'.$y.'</td>';
   print '<td>['.$z.']</td>';
   print '<td></td>';
   print '</tr>';

   }
}
```

The following is the output that I get. Now array for $lines that didn't display properly.

```
------------------------------------------------
| Title     |    No    | Lines       | Remarks |
------------------------------------------------
| Book A    |    2     | Maria       |         |
| Book B    |    1     | Maria       |         |
| Book C    |    4     | Maria       |         |
------------------------------------------------
```